# Javascript, number comparison not working as expected?

Tags: javascript, numbers

Why in console I see false?

```
console.log(0.1 + 0.2 == 0.3);
```

Comment: Because you can't compare floating point numbers. You need to check their difference - `console.log(0.1 + 0.2 - 0.3 < 0.001);`

Comment: Take a look at [How to deal with floating point number precision in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458633/how-to-deal-with-floating-point-number-precision-in-javascript)